# Sybase Central: How to set language for UI of Sybase Central

Tags: sybase-sql-anywhere, sybase-central, l10n

How to set the language for UI of Sybase Central.. It appears it's taking the language settings from Windows, but having e.g. an English Sybase Central on a German Windows -- how to achieve this?

For database server and other tools it can be set either via `SALANG` environmental variable or via the tool `dblang`. On Linux you can just say somethng like

```
LANG=C scjview
```

but this seems not to work on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `dblang` command, but you need to disable fast launcher first.

See this for reference: [Changing administration tool language settings](http://dcx.sap.com/1200/en/dbadmin/da-guitools-s-5315498.html)

Comment: Even after deactivating of fast launcher it does not work. dblang is showing EN as user language, but scjview is starting with DE.

Comment: Just tried it on a clean Windows with a complete fresh installation of SQLAnywhere12 with PL90 and it appears to work. On other system maybe issue due to installation of different versions at the same time etc.